# Why am I receiving "not enough values" when running an INSERT?

Tags: sql, oracle

Couldn't get the right approach to automatically set the id value in my table with Oracle. Here's my trigger:

```
create or replace trigger themes_on_insert
before insert on THEME
for each row
begin
   :new.ID := THEMES_SEQ.nextval;
end;
```

I have two columns: id, description. But when i call insert

```
insert into theme values('Sport');
```

it gives me

> Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
>   00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"

Comment: Well the error just tells you, that you didn´t include enough values in the `values` clause. As you didn´t specify the columns you´re inserting there, it expects each column to be present in the `values` clause, which it most like isn´t the case right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure to name the columns you're specifying the values for.

```
insert into theme (description) values('Sport');
```

Answer (score 6):

You do not specify the columns you are supplying values for, so the database expects a value for **every** column in your table.

Assuming you have a column `name` in that table, you need to do this:

```
insert into theme (name) values('Sport');
```

Not listing the target columns in an `INSERT` statement is bad coding style.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you do not specify the colnames, in your insert statement, the databse will assume that you give the values for all the column.

So :

```
insert into theme (col_name) values ('Sport');
```

Answer (score 1):

In case Trigger is not mandatory,You can simply use the following

```
 insert into theme values(THEMES_SEQ.nextval,'Sport');
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the columns count while inserting.