# Insert data on the same table with different cursors

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, cursor, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to do a procedure with 3 different cursors, obtaining data from the same table.

The first cursor only obtains the collections, the second cursor obtains the invoices, the third cursor obtains the credit notes.

```
create or replace procedure COMISIONCALCULO
IS 
    CURSOR COB IS 
         SELECT ASIENTOCONTABLE, 
                fedocoriginal2, 
                importedebe 
         FROM INFGENERAL 
         WHERE TIPODEASIENTO2 = 'Cobro';

cursor FACT (P1 IN VARCHAR2) is 
      select IDCOMPESACION, 
             ASIENTOCONTABLE, 
             FEDOCORIGINAL2, 
             FEVENCIMIENTO,
             IDDOCORIGINAL
     FROM INFGENERAL
     WHERE TIPODEASIENTO2 in ('Migración de datos','Factura de cliente')
    AND ASIENTOCONTABLE =P1;

CURSOR NOTAS (P1 IN VARCHAR2) IS 
     SELECT fecontabilizacion,
            fedocoriginal,
            iddocoriginal,
            tipodeasiento2,
            importedebe
     FROM INFGENERAL 
     WHERE TIPODEASIENTO2 = 'Nota de crédito de cliente'
     AND IDDOCORIGINAL= P1;
```

I join the cursors because a charge affects one or more bills and those bills have one or more credit notes.

When I define the cursors I add variables P1.

I want to save all the data obtained in another table but as a single record. Except the final table has different columns than the source table.

Origin Table:

```
CREATE TABLE  "INFGENERAL" 
   (    "CLIENTE" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "FECONTABILIZACION" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "FEDOCORIGINAL" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "FEVENCIMIENTO" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "TIPODEASIENTO" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "ASIENTOCONTABLE" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "ASIENTOCONTCOM" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "IDCOMPESACION" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "IDDOCORIGINAL" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "REFEXTERNA" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "ESTADO" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "IDFACTURA" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "FECHACOMPENSACION" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "IDDOCREF" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "IMPORTEPENDIENTE" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "IMPORTEDEBE" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "IMPORTEHABER" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "TIPODEASIENTO2" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "FEDOCORIGINAL2" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "FEVENCIMIENTO2" VARCHAR2(60)
   ) ;
```

Final table:

```
CREATE TABLE  "INFOFINAL" 
   (    "ASIENTOCONTABLE" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "FECHACOBRO" DATE, 
    "IMPORTECOBRO" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "IDCOMPESACION" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "IDDOCORIGINAL" VARCHAR2(60), 
    "FECHAORIGFACT" DATE, 
    "FECHAVENFACT" DATE, 
    "IMPORTEHABERNOTA" VARCHAR2(60)
   ) ;
```

The problem is when I try to run the procedure it marks me
"not enough valuesCompilation failed"
This error is marked on the lines of the insert.

```
BEGIN 
    FOR I IN COB LOOP
        INSERT INTO INFOFINAL 
        VALUES (I.ASIENTOCONTABLE, I.FECHACOBRO, I.IMPORTECOBRO);

        FOR J IN FACT(I.ASIENTOCONTABLE) LOOP
            INSERT INTO INFOFINAL 
            VALUES(J.IDCOMPESACION,J.IDDOCORIGINAL, J.FECHAORIGFACT, J.FECHAVENFACT);
            FOR H IN NOTAS(J.IDDOCORIGINAL) LOOP
                INSERT INTO INFOFINAL 
                VALUES(H.IMPORTEHABERNOTA);
                CNOTA:= CNOTA + 1;
            END LOOP;

            CFACT := CFACT + 1;
    END LOOP;
    CCOB:= CCOB + 1;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

The question here is, how can I insert the selected data from the source table to the final table when they have different columns? Should the columns have the same name? Can I insert the insert only once?

Please help.

Comment: There are fewer fields on your INSERT statements than there are in the table you're inserting into, and you haven't included a field list on the INSERTs so it's not clear which fields from the cursors are supposed to go into the various fields on INFOFINAL. I suspect you can use a single cursor and a single INSERT, but because I can't work out how the fields are supposed to match up I can't come up with a recommendation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I receiving "not enough values" when running an INSERT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979954/why-am-i-receiving-not-enough-values-when-running-an-insert)

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to save all the data obtained in another table but as a single record"

If you want a single record you need just the one insert.

Inner loops inherit scope from their outer loops, so you can reference all three cursors from the innermost loop, like this:

```
BEGIN 
    FOR I IN COB LOOP

        FOR J IN FACT(I.ASIENTOCONTABLE) LOOP

            FOR H IN NOTAS(J.IDDOCORIGINAL) LOOP
                INSERT INTO INFOFINAL 
                VALUES(I.ASIENTOCONTABLE, 
                       I.FECHACOBRO, 
                       I.IMPORTECOBRO, 
                       J.IDCOMPESACION,
                       J.IDDOCORIGINAL, 
                       J.FECHAORIGFACT, 
                       J.FECHAVENFACT,
                       H.IMPORTEHABERNOTA);
                CNOTA:= CNOTA + 1;
            END LOOP;

            CFACT := CFACT + 1;
        END LOOP;
        CCOB:= CCOB + 1;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

---

> PLS-00302: component 'IMPORTEHABERNOTA' must be declared
>   Compilation failed.

As it turns out there is no column `IMPORTEHABERNOTA` on the source table `INFGENERAL`. So this version of the procedure won't work. There is no obvious other candidate on the table, so there is no way we can determine how to fix `CURSOR NOTAS`. The OP needs to use their understanding of their data model to solve this.

Comment: I tried to do that but he sent me the following errors.

PLS-00302: component 'IMPORTEHABERNOTA' must be declaredCompilation failed.

PL / SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed hereCompilation failed.

My question is, is there a problem in which the columns have different names?

Comment: So what column in `INFGENERAL` table maps to `INFOFINAL.IMPORTEHABERNOTA`? It's your data model, you should know it, because there's zero chance some random stranger on the internet can explain it to you.